# Ruby - Parsing text files efficiently

Tags: html, ruby, string, parsing

I am trying to parse `href` tags in `HTML`. Basically I am trying to get the URL and the description. I also try to split description by whitespace and count the amount of each word occurrence, finally write them down to two separate files. My parser works fine, however it is really inefficient, I would say it parses 1MB of text in 2 minutes.

The below is my code:

```
hrefTag = "<a href=\""
qtMark = "\""
descStart = "\">"
hrefEnd = "</a>"
if line.include? hrefTag 
    dest = line[/#{hrefTag}(.*?)#{qtMark}/m, 1]
    descStIn = line.rindex(descStart)
    descEndIn = line.rindex(hrefEnd)
    if (descStIn != nil && descEndIn != nil)
        desc = line[(descStIn+2)..(descEndIn-1)]
    end
end
if (source != "" && dest != "")
    occur = Hash.new(0)
    mainEntry = "original-url=\"" + source + 
    "\", dest-url=\"" + dest + "\"" 
    descEntry = ""
    if (desc != nil && desc != "")
        descEntry = ", desc=\"" + desc + "\""
        words = desc.split(' ')
        words.each { |word| occur[word] += 1 }
    end
    firstEntry = mainEntry+descEntry+"\n\n"
    File.open(firstOutput, 'a') { |file| 
        file.write(firstEntry) 
    }
    occur.each { |word, occurrance| 
        wordEntry = ", word=\"" + word +
        "\", count=" + occurrance.to_s
        secondEntry = mainEntry+wordEntry+"\n\n"
        File.open(secondOutput, 'a') { |file| 
            file.write(secondEntry) 
        }
    }
```

How can I make it more efficient? What parts are the most inefficient?

Comment: use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).... it will make your life easy.

Answer (score 0):

To see what's taking the most time, profile your code with [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) or similar tool. To install ruby-prof:

```
gem install ruby-prof
```

Run it to call your script:

```
ruby-prof <script.rb>
```

When your script completes (or if you CTRL-C), it summarizes method calls, time taken in each method, etc. Here's a snippet of output:

```
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
  8.67      0.008     0.008     0.000     0.000        2   JSON::Ext::Parser#parse 
  8.45      0.022     0.008     0.000     0.014       99   IO#read_nonblock 
  6.66      0.006     0.006     0.000     0.000       99   <Module::Kernel>#select 
  2.78      0.003     0.003     0.000     0.000      235   IO#write 
  1.17      0.001     0.001     0.000     0.000       57   Enumerator#next 
  0.99      0.049     0.001     0.000     0.048      207  *Array#each
```